# Android Studio - Return error msg when sql query search record does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-application

I have created an android application with a built in sqlite database, the user makes a search and the data is shown. Everything works wonderfully however i am totally stuck on getting an error message to popup when what the user searches for does not exist.

Rather than returning nothing i would like to have a popup message saying "Record does not exist!"

This may be simple but every IF statement i try has errors, would appreciate any pointers.

My query code:

```
   public String getProduct(String userInput){
    c=db.rawQuery("select productname from Inventory where productname ='"+userInput+"'", new String[]{});
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        String product = c.getString(0);
        buffer.append(""+product);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Before your while loop you can check if the query returned any data and if not just return an empty String

`if(!c.moveToFirst()) return ""`

When you use `getProduct` you could check if it is empty or not

```
String dbResult = getProduct(userInput);
if(dbResult.isEmpty) {
  // Display "Record does not exist!"
}
```